# Exposing Python Script as an API or Service

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-services, flask, flask-restful

I am using Python for quite a while. I have integrated my python code with java UI as well and is working fine.

Now here comes the tricky part.

I need to expose my python script as an API so that it can be executed from anywhere (Any other suggestions to achieve this are also welcomed) without depending on one particular machine where the python scripts are present.

My initial basic code snippet is given below for your reference :

```
import .....

def main(id1, id2):
    do something ........
    call sub-function(id1, id2)
    do something ........

if __name__ == '__main__':

    id1 = sys.argv[1] #Getting first argument from Java UI.
    id1 = sys.argv[1] #Getting first argument from Java UI.
    main(id1, id2)    #Calling Main function using two IDs as arguments.
```

This code is working fine as long as I point to the script path in my system from java. But I need to change this code structure to expose it as an API or Service. I do not have any idea on how to achieve this. With help of few articles, I tried my luck with Flask framework. But I am not sure how to call main function using flask by supplying arguments.

```
import .....
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    do something ........
    id1 = app.config.get['ID1']
    id2 = app.config.get['ID2']
    call sub-function(id1, id2)
    do something ........

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #For simplicity I supplied the arguments' values manually instead of getting it from java.
    app.config['ID1'] = 101
    app.config['ID2'] = 2

    app.run(debug=True)

    #Commented out calling main function since app.run() will take care
    #main(id1, id2)    #Calling Main function using two IDs as arguments.
```

When I execute this and goes to default web address (http://127.0.0.1:5000), I am getting the below error

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
>
> Traceback (most recent call last) File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1997, in **call** return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1985, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1540, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 33, in reraise raise value File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1982, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1614, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1517, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 33, in reraise raise value File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1612, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
>   "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1598, in dispatch_request return
>   self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
>   **"C:\Users\user_name\Main_Script.py", line 29, in main id1 =
>   app.config.get['ID1'] TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object
>   is not subscriptable** The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI
>   application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
>   To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you
>   can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can
>   also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you
>   want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.
>
> You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there
>   are some extra helpers available for introspection:
>
> dump() shows all variables in the frame dump(obj) dumps all that's
>   known about the object

**Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this and how to execute this script from any machine by exposing it as an API or service.**

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are looking to remotely call the Python function and pass arguments into it and get back the result.

For example:

```
@app.route('/<string:idOne>/<string:idTwo>')
def main(idOne,idTwo):
    do something
    return something
```

Now you can just make a HTTP GET request. 
For example:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/myFirstArg/mySecondArg

Comment: Thank you @UssiSonad .But after creating a http link I am not able to access it from some other machine. For example : Assume that in my machine I am able to create a link as "http://127.0.0.1:5000/myFirstArg/mySecondArg". So I believe if i replace the 127.0.0.1 with my system IP Address and try to connect from some other machine it should work. But I am getting "Connection Refused" Network Error (tcp_error). Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: It is because the Flask server is meant to be only the development server not the one you expose. It is not by default accessible remotely.You need a seperate way of deploying the code.  Have a look at this http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/ . Localtunnel might fit your need.

Comment: I cannot manually fetch the link created by the Localtunnel. So it won't be of much help to me. But I figured out myself. you need to start the app by app.run(host = '0.0.0.0') in the client machine. Then you can access the app from another machine using client machine's ip address instead of 127.0.0.1